# how can I add a command in terminal to open a file

Tags: command-line, execute-command

I save a file **Logisim2.7.1.jar** in my directory at `/home/danny/Application`.
Whenever I want to run this file in terminal, i have to type these following line in terminal:

```
 cd /home/danny/Application
 java -jar logisim.2.7.1.jar
```

Then the file will execute.

My question is: instead of typing all that command line in terminal, can I just type `logisim` in my terminal and the file will execute?

I did this before by doing the following steps which im not sure, if you know, please correct me:

1. Create a folder called "bin" in home directories.
2. Create a text file inside the bin folder, and add this line **java -jar logisim.2.7.1.jar** then save it as **logisim.txt**
3. I then edit the `.bashrc` file by adding this line at the bottom:
   `PATH=$PATH: home/familypc/bin/`
4. After that I did something with `chmod` in my command line which i forgot to make terminal to look in the new bin directories.
   any helps?

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is probably this:

1. `mkdir ~/.local/bin`

   This will create the directory `.local/bin` inside your home, which is sightly better than just `bin` (although `bin` is OK, too).
2. Add to your `.bashrc` the line `PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"`
3. Create the file `~/.local/bin/logisim` and write something like this:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   java -jar $HOME/full/path/to/logisim.2.7.1.jar
   ```

   Note: the file is called `logisim`, without the `.txt` extension. Also note that you need to specify the full path to the jar file.
4. `chmod +x ~/.local/bin/logisim`

Now you can restart your shell and enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply create and alias by adding the following line to your .bashrc:

```
alias logisim='java -jar /home/danny/Applications/logisim.2.7.1.jar'
```

...then reload .bashrc with

```
source ~/.bashrc
```